# Compress sourcecode excluding binaries

Tags: powershell

I want to write a script for our build server (windows machine).

One part is extracting the binaries and deleting all debugging files. I have the code for that already.

The second part is getting the sourcefiles of the project (WPF) and compress it, excluding the /bin/ and /obj/ folders.

What I've got so far is:

```
#
# Get and zip Sourcefiles
#

# Get relevant folders and files
[string[]]$FolderExcludes = @('*bin*', '*obj*')

$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Exclude $FolderExcludes | %{ 
    $allowed = $true
    foreach ($exclude in $FolderExcludes) { 
        if ((Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent) -ilike $exclude) { 
            $allowed = $false
            break
        }
    }
    if ($allowed) {
        $_
    }
}

[string[]]$FileExcludes = @('*.git*', 'sonar-project.properties')

$Files = $Folders | Get-ChildItem -File | %{
    $allowed = $true

    foreach ($exclude in $FileExcludes) { 
        if ($_.Name -ilike $exclude) { 
            $allowed = $false
            break
        }
    }
    if ($allowed) {
        $_.FullName
    }
}

$Files
```

The List of files contains all files I want to zip. But when I do

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$Files | %{ sz a -mx=9 "$SourcePath\$ArtifactPath.zip" $_ }
```

it gets all files and places them into root.

When I try to zip the folders, 7zip takes all folders, includes bin and obj and includes the hidden .git folders (which we don't tend to release with the source code).

So how can I compress the source file without the bin/obj folders and without breaking the filepaths insidde the zip?

btw I tried to delete the folders, after the build process and after copying the binaries into their export-folder, but the powershell seems to hold the files so I can't delete it at that time :(

A more stupid idea would be copying all of that and deleting the bin and obj folders there.. but it seems to be very inefficient.

And I don't need to use 7zip. I'm perfectly fine with winzip or anything else. Just wanted to compress the sourcecode.

Comment: Which version of PS you use. PS 5 natively support  zip archiving with compress-archive and expand-archive cmdlets.

Comment: Yes, I use PS 5 (Windows 10, not yet 1607). Does compress-archive have any useful except commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on SuperUser: https://superuser.com/a/97347/440614

```
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
sz a -mx=9 "$SourcePath\$ArtifactPath.zip" FolderToArchive\ -mx0 -xr!bin -xr!obj -xr!.git, -xr!sonar-project.properties
```

...may need tweaking, but should give you a good start.

Comment: I saw commands like these but they didn't work.. but I'll give it a try later and mark as solution, if it works. Thank you!

Comment: This worked: ``sz a -mx=9 "$SourcePath\$ArtifactPath.zip" .\ -xr!bin -xr!obj -xr!"$ArtifactPath" -xr0!"$ArtifactPath.zip.tmp" -xr0!".git" -xr0!".gitignore" -xr0!".gitmodules" -xr0!"sonar-project.properties"`` It doesn't copy folders or files with the exact name "obj" and "bin", it also doesn't copy the hidden ".git"-folder or all other files in the first level directory (0-flag). Works like a charm. Thank you :)